# How to check a data.frame for any non-finite

Tags: r

I'd like to check if a data.frame has any non-finite elements.

This seems to evaluate each column, returning FALSE for each (I'm guessing its evaluating the data.frame as a list):

```
any( !is.finite( x ) )
```

I don't understand why this behaves differently from the above, but it works fine if just checking for NAs:

```
any( !is.na( x ) )
```

I'd like the solution to be as efficient as possible.  I realize I can just do...

```
any( !is.finite( as.matrix( x ) ) )
```

Comment: Efficiency is good, but ... do you have any evidence that the speed of this test is (or is going to be) a bottleneck in your analysis?

Comment: Its unlikely to be a bottleneck.  I see this question as an opportunity to learn more about R.  I'm wondering if I'm missing some technique to evaluate the elements in a data.frame other than the obvious technique of converting to a different data-type

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you type `methods(is.na)` you'll see that it has a `data.frame` method, which probably explains why it works the way you expect, where `is.finite` does not. The usual solution would be to write one yourself, since it's only one line. Something like this maybe,

```
is.finite.data.frame <- function(obj){
    sapply(obj,FUN = function(x) all(is.finite(x)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to methods() as well as the solution!  I would use "all" instead of "any" and define a finite data.frame column as a column with only finites

Comment: @SFun28 Good point, thanks. Typed a little too quick. Edited to reflect your point.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming the error you are getting is the following:

```
> any( is.infinite( z ) )
Error in is.infinite(z) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

This error is because the `is.infinite()` and the `is.finite()` functions are not implemented with a method for data.frames. The `is.na()` function does have a data.frame method.

The way to work around this is to `apply()` the function to every row, column, or element in the data.frame. Here's an example using `sapply()` to apply the `is.infinite()` function to each element:

```
x <- c(1:10, NA)
y <- c(1:11)
z <- data.frame(x,y)
any( sapply(z, is.infinite) )
 ## or

any( ! sapply(z, is.finite) )
```

Answer (score 3):

One difference is that `is.na` and `is.finite` are different types of functions.  `is.na` is a generic and will dispatch based on the class of the argument.

```
> methods("is.na")
[1] is.na.data.frame      is.na.numeric_version is.na.POSIXlt        
[4] is.na.raster*        

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Note in particular that there is an `is.na.data.frame` function.  Looking at that function:

```
> is.na.data.frame
function (x) 
{
    y <- do.call("cbind", lapply(x, "is.na"))
    if (.row_names_info(x) > 0L) 
        rownames(y) <- row.names(x)
    y
}
<bytecode: 00000000054F40F0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

the part that does the work is the `do.call("cbind", lapply(x, "is.na"))` call which puts columns together (`cbind`) which are the result of `lapply(x, "is.na")`.  Running just this with an example data.frame (mtcars):

```
> lapply(mtcars, "is.na")
$mpg
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$cyl
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$disp
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$hp
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$drat
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$wt
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$qsec
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$vs
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$am
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$gear
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$carb
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

we see that this is really just a column-wise computation, put back together into a data.frame.

Compare that to `is.finite` which does not have a specific function for data.frames:

```
> methods("is.finite")
no methods were found
```

In fact, it is a primitive method, meaning that the details are in C code, not R code.

```
> is.finite
function (x)  .Primitive("is.finite")
```

If you want to do a column-wise computation with `is.finite`, you can wrap it like `is.na.data.frame` does.

```
> do.call(cbind, lapply(mtcars, is.finite))
       mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb
 [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [6,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [7,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [8,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [9,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[10,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[11,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[12,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[13,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[14,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[15,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[16,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[17,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[18,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[19,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[20,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[21,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[22,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[23,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[24,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[25,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[26,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[27,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[28,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[29,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[30,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[31,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[32,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This latter could also be gotten as

```
sapply(mtcars, is.finite)
```

No testing on what would be most efficient, though.

Comment: thanks, Brian!  I appreciated the breakdown of is.na.data.frame

Answer (score 3):

Your solution of calling `as.matrix` will only work if the `data.frame` only has numeric columns. Otherwise, the matrix will typically become a character matrix and the result will be false everywhere...

@joran has a good approach, but you'll have problems with factor columns unless to add a method for factors too etc...

```
is.finite(letters[1:3])         # FALSE - OK
is.finite(factor(letters[1:3])) # TRUE - WRONG!!

is.finite.factor <- function(obj){
    logical(length(obj))
}

is.finite(factor(letters[1:3])) # FALSE - OK
```

Also, if you want the check to be as fast as possible, you should avoid `sapply` and go for `vapply` instead.

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(runif(1e6), nrow=10), letters[1:10])

# @joran's method
is.finite.data.frame <- function(obj){
    sapply(obj,FUN = function(x) all(is.finite(x)))
}

system.time( x <- is.finite(d) ) # 0.42 secs

# Using vapply instead...
is.finite.data.frame <- function(obj) {
    vapply(obj,FUN = function(x) all(is.finite(x)), logical(1))
}

system.time( y <- is.finite(d) ) # 0.20 secs

identical(x,y) # TRUE
```

Comment: Great points about as.matrix, factor columns, and vapply!  This answer is chock-full of good stuff.  =)