# ggmosaic error message: default method not implemented for type 'list'

Tags: ggplot2, mosaic-plot, ggmosaic

Trying to create a heatmap using `ggmosaic`, I keep getting the error `Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'`

Searching for that error message, one answer was that "This error is because the is.infinite() and the is.finite() functions are not implemented with a method for data.frames." [But not a useful solution in the question nor about ggmosaic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173094/how-to-check-a-data-frame-for-any-non-finite)

Even the example from the vignette fails for me.

```
ggplot(data = NHANES) +
   geom_mosaic(aes(weight = Weight, x = product(SleepHrsNight), fill=factor(SleepHrsNight)), na.rm=TRUE) +
   labs(x="Hours of sleep a night ", title='f(SleepHrsNight)') + guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "SleepHrsNight", reverse = TRUE))
```

My system is Windows, RStudio, R version one before the most current, and `ggmosaic` Ver 0.1.2

The made-up data frame I want to use is

```
structure(list(Diversity = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AfricanAm", "Asian", "Cauc.", "Latino", 
"Other"), class = "factor"), Office = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Hamlet", "MainTown", "Metroprole", 
"Smithville", "Urbanburg"), class = "factor"), JrAssoc = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 
5, 9, 10), SrAssPtr = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 
5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), .Names = c("Diversity", 
"Office", "JrAssoc", "SrAssPtr"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

This code has not succeeded:

```
ggplot(diverse) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(weight = 1, x = product(JrAssoc, SrAssPtr), fill = Diversity))
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Hi @lawyeR, I don't have a straight answer for you.  But check this thread on github: https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/issues/9

Answer (score 1):

If you just update your ggplot2 library in this way

```
devtools::install_github('cran/ggplot2')
```

your problem should be solved.

As mentioned in my [comments](https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/issues/9), author are trying to fix the issue.

Comment: > devtools::install_github('cran/ggplot2')
Installation failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Comment: mmmh... strange!  Can you install any other libraries with install_github?