# Error in is.finite(x) using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run a simple F test between two series' in R using:

```
var.test(fit1,fit2)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I have tried fixing the problem using the suggestions in these threads:
https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/issues/9
[ggmosaic error message: default method not implemented for type 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101713/ggmosaic-error-message-default-method-not-implemented-for-type-list)

By running:

```
devtools::install_github('cran/ggplot2', force = TRUE)
```

Although this line runs fine - the error persists. I tried uninstalling ggplot2 and repeating the process, and restarting R in each case.

My initial code to create fit1 and fit2 is this:
This model is created based on an economic index imported from a CSV file:

```
index_ma = ma(df_ind$weight_ind_2, order=7)
count_ma = ts(na.omit(index_ma), frequency=30)
decomp = stl(count_ma, s.window="periodic")
deseasonal_cnt <- seasadj(decomp)
fit1<-auto.arima(deseasonal_cnt, seasonal=FALSE)
```

This model is created based on daily S&P data over 10 years imported from a CSV file:

```
econ_ma = ma(df_daily$sp_change, order=7)
econ_count_ma = ts(na.omit(econ_ma), frequency=30)
econ_decomp = stl(econ_count_ma, s.window="periodic")
econ_decomped <- seasadj(econ_decomp)
fit2<-auto.arima(econ_decomped, seasonal=FALSE)
```

I have run some other tests on the two series' previously - both have the same number of observations and no other problems. It ran no problem until I updated R the other day and now I receive this error.

Any help would be really appreciated as before I updated the package the code ran no problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This is a rather common error message which is why your research on how to fix the problem led you down a erroneous path. I think it is safe to say that your error has nothing to do with `ggplot2` since this is a library for plotting. If you provided us with more information on your objects `fit1` and `fit2`, or even gave us a snapshot of your data, we would be more more likely to be able to help you!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer - I will add some more details now which hopefully can help.

Comment: These are complex model objects and you can't simply run an F-test on them. What is your goal, specifically? Do you want to assess which model fits the data better?

Comment: `var.test` is only designed for numeric vectors or linear models of class `lm`. It is attempting to call `is.finite` on your arima object assuming it is a numeric vector.

Comment: I want to see if the two series' are significantly similar to each other. I was trying by building an ARIMA model for each series and F-test to compare their variance. But I'm totally open to any way to compare them that is more statistically sound!