# R: Check for finite values in DataFrame

Tags: r

I need to check whether data frame is "empty" or not ("empty" in a sense that dataframe contain zero **finite** value. If there is mix of finite and non-finite value, it should NOT be considered "empty")

Referring to [How to check a data.frame for any non-finite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173094/how-to-check-a-data-frame-for-any-non-finite), I came up with one line code to almost achieve this objective

```
nrow(tmp[rowSums(sapply(tmp, function(x) is.finite(x))) > 0,]) == 0
```

where tmp is some data frame.

This code works fine for most cases, but it fails if data frame contains a single row.

For example, the above code would work fine for,

```
tmp <- data.frame(a=c(NA,NA), b=c(NA,NA)) OR tmp <- data.frame(a=c(3,NA), b=c(4,NA))
```

But not for,

```
tmp <- data.frame(a=NA, b=NA)
```

because I think rowSums expects at least two rows

I looked at some other posts such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/how-to-calculate-the-rowmeans-with-some-single-rows-in-data, but I still couldn't come up a solution for my problem.

My question is, are there any clean ways (i.e. avoid using loops and ideally one liner) to check for being "empty" for any dataframes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are checking all columns, then you can just do

```
all(sapply(tmp, is.finite))
```

Here we are using `all` rather than the `rowSums` trick so we don't have to worry about preserving matrices.

Comment: I just tried your code, but it seems to fail for cases where dataframe has mix of finite and non-finite values (e.g. tmp <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,NA), b=c(3,4,NA)). Maybe I should've clarified my problem. If there is at least one finite value in the data frame, it shouldn 't be considered "empty"

Comment: Then just change `all()` to `any()`